# Application crash on power button

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am making a game(Landscape mode) in AndEngine GLES 2.0 and facing very weird problem. When I press *power button -> power button -> unlock phone*, the game restarts automatically. I've done some testing:

**Not working:**

- Galaxy Nexus (4.2.1)
- Xperia Pro (4.0.4)

**Working:**

- Xperia Pro (2.3.4)

I wonder if there is some change in the power button management of 4.0. and above?
If I change my game to portrait mode then there is no problem at all.

I also have placed the `orientationChanged` settings in the manifest but the problem still exists

Comment: How come that `Xperia Pro (2.3.4)` is both working and not working?

Comment: `I also have placed the orientationChanged settings in the manifest`.  You mean "I used a hack which Google says should only be used as a last resort to hide the fact I have bugs". Even if you fix this bug, your app will crash when someone plugs a keyboard in, or slides out a physical keyboard, or changes the timezone, or changes the language or any one of a number of reasons why your Activity will be destroyed.  Please read about, and understand, the Activity life cycle then look again at your code.  You are doing something wrong in the onCreate(), onPause(), onResume() cycle.

Comment: sorry I mistyped , its not working on XPERIA 4.0.4 , the life cycle execution is fine, maybe there is some problem with the basegameactivity

LogCat:
<code></code>

Comment: Logcat: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70467204/log.txt

Comment: What code you have write in onResume and onPause method? As per my view there is definitely problem in these sections.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem that was similar, but not resulting in an application crash. Just that the game did not restart successfully. It turned out the problem for me was using static references.
Your problem may be caused by your textures. I don't think its documented anywhere, but using ANY static reference to a texture can cause a number of bad outcomes when resuming a game. However its fine to use a Singleton to manage your textures.

Comment: To avoid any memory issues, I haven't used any static references in my game other then the Game Constants. I Downloaded apps made on gles2, and those using BaseGameActivity have the same issue of  crashing